# Need help for identifying SMD component

Tags: identification, surface-mount

I've got a lenovo tablet (lenovo ideapad miix 300) from my friend, upon opening it, i found a burned out smd component that is the same component shown in the picture. I need help identifying this component, because I want to fix the tablet. Thanks.
I've tried to google the part number, but no luck.
[image: the element]

The burned component:
[image: burned component]

The component caused the tablet to show that its charging when the battery connector is plugged in, even without no charger attached. Other effect is that the cpu heatsink becomes warm, but no picture is shown and the tablet cannot be turned on.

Here is picture of other components around the burned component. (red are pads of the burned out component that is desoldered at the moment)
[image: components around the burned component]

Here are some pictures that show where the components are located at the tablets motherboard.
[image: Overview of the MB]
[image: More closeup of the area]

Sorry for my English, I am not native English speaker.

Comment: What have you done so far in trying to identify this part?

Comment: What makes you think that the burnt component is the source of the problem or just a symptom? If the problem is elsewhere, if you change that component it will burn again.

Comment: You may be out of luck.  A lot of high volume products use components made specifically for that company and not publicly available.  It's probably just a pass transistor or LDO but you may not find it listed anywhere.  Even common components these days use a 'top mark' rather than a part number which makes them hard to trace.

Comment: Thanks for all your suggestions, I have updated my post with additional informations.